# Django block page title

Tags: html, django

I'm trying to create a custom page title for each page but I've not been successfull. The following is the general setup for all my html pages (And what I thought would work; it doesn't) and would appreciate any solutions.

head.html

```
something something
<title>{% block title %}Default Value{% endblock title %}</title>
something something
```

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

{% include "head.html" %}

<body>
    {% include 'header.html' %}

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}

    {% include 'footer.html' %}
    {% include 'scripts.html' %}
</body>
</html>
```

404 html file

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}404{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<div id="main404">
        <div class="fof">
                <h1>Error 404 :(</h1>
        </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Currently it still displays the default value indicated in head.html. I would like to customise the page title of each page using the block as attempted above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 404 html file extends `base.html` not `head.html` meaning it won't fill the blocks of `head.html`. `head.html` is **included** into `base.html` meaning it is compiled and rendered separately and is not extended by the template which is extending `base.html`.
As referenced from [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include):

> The include tag should be considered as an implementation of “render
> this subtemplate and include the HTML”, not as “parse this subtemplate
> and include its contents as if it were part of the parent”. This means
> that there is no shared state between included templates – each
> include is a completely independent rendering process.

The simplest way would be to put the block in `base.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    something something
    <title>{% block title %}Default Value{% endblock title %}</title>
    something something
</head>
<body>
    {% include 'header.html' %}

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}

    {% include 'footer.html' %}
    {% include 'scripts.html' %}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

one way of doing this while keeping your file structure as it is would be to send title as parameter in django's include method as follows:

Update your files as follows:

**base.html**

*create a new block named headcontent and include head.html with default title*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

{% block headcontent %}{% include head.html with title="Default Title" %}{% endblock %}
<body>
    {% include 'header.html' %}
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}
    {% include 'footer.html' %}
    {% include 'scripts.html' %}
</body>

</html>
```

---

**404.html**

*provide value to headcontent block as head.html with title of your desire, 404 in this case.*

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block headcontent %}{% include head.html with title="404" %}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div id="main404">
        <div class="fof">
                <h1>Error 404 :(</h1>
        </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

---

**head.html**

```
something something
<title>{{title}}</title>
something something
```

To know more about using include with parameters check [include in django template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#include)

Answer (score 0):

The `block` tag can only be overriden by children templates, those that use the `extends` tag. Your block tag for the title is nested in a include template statement (head.html). If you have a large head block that you need to include for other templates then I can see inheritance being helpful.

## head.html

```
something something
<title>{% block title %}Default Value{% endblock title %}</title>
something something
```

## head_404.html

```
{% extends 'head.html' %}
{% block title %}404{% endblock %}
```

## base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

{% block head %}
    {% include "head.html" %}
{% endblock %}

<body>
    {% include 'header.html' %}

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}

    {% include 'footer.html' %}
    {% include 'scripts.html' %}
</body>
</html>
```

## 404.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block head %}
    {% include "head_404.html" %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div id="main404">
        <div class="fof">
                <h1>Error 404 :(</h1>
        </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

You could skip the head_404.html file and simply define the head children tags in the 404.html template as well.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block head %}

    ... stuff

    <title>404</title>

{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div id="main404">
        <div class="fof">
                <h1>Error 404 :(</h1>
        </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```